# Can't get the Sessions to work in webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to pass variables from one page to another using Sessions , but they don't seem to have effect. In the source page inside the razor syntax

```
    Session["variable"] = "value";
```

And in the target page:

```
    <p>@Session["variable"].ToString()</p>
```

but I get a server error

```
    Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome........Thanks

Comment: Have you tried casting instead? I know that many will say that `.ToString()` should work, but in reality, I wasn't able to use `.ToString()` and had to use `(string)Session["variable"]` instead.

Comment: Did casting help? Were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: Actually No. There was a problem in the scope, but it still produces undesired results.

Comment: What's it doing? Did you make sure there was no space between `@(string)` and `Session["variable"]`? If you can be more specific about "undesired results" I may be able to further assist you.

Answer (score 1):

I was only ever able to get this to work with casting:

```
<p>@(string)Session["variable"]</p>
```

Although it has been a long time since I have tried it with `ToString()` instead, I do explicitly remember my attempt to call a Session variable only successful with the casting option, although I have heard that `ToString()` should work. Either way, I always get it to work with casting.

That having been said, I feel it only right of me to warn you that if you are simply trying to pass data between pages, you shouldn't be using Session variables at all. Use hidden form fields, query strings, Url Data, or even cookies and/or databases before you do that.

I like to look at Session variables as something to quickly solve very special cases and only to be used very CAREFULLY. ALWAYS expect the value to be null and test its value before using it.

For help with the options for transferring data between web pages using WebMatrix, check out Mike Brind's very helpful site: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages `<-- You'll want to bookmark this for now. It is right up the alley of what you are getting yourself into with WebMatrix.`

If you still want to use the Session variable and casting doesn't work, the only other thing I can think that would cause the error is that the value you expect in `Session["variable"]` isn't what you think it is.

**For the Record:**

*I was only trying to make a point when saying, "or even cookies and/or databases before you do that" Please do not use those options, as they are likely terrible in your case (also, cookies would just give you the same problems as Session variables, actually). In any case, it really all depends on how you are using the data and if you are always checking to make sure the value hasn't been cleared in the case of Session variables and/or cookies.*